# Where can I find dividend payout frequencies?

Tags: dividends, ex-dividend-date

Most equities pay out dividends each quarter, but some equities like [DIV](https://www.vanguard.idmanagedsolutions.com/stocks/historicalDividends?symbol=DIV) pay out every month. Is there an API or hard coded list available with the payout frequency per equity? Or is it safe to calculate this based on last year's payout frequency?

Comment: API's are available for past historical dividends paid and current fiscal year dividends per share.some API's are available on subscription basis for frequent investors to get dividend details.

Comment: @Kannan I am well aware of this, but none of the APIs I could find provide frequency information.

Comment: @brt it wouldn’t be too hard to find that yourself from an API that provides historical ex-dividends, just count the number of arrays returned for each ex date in a fiscal year and that would be your frequency.

Comment: @NuWin That's a work around indeed, just thought this info was easily available.

Answer (score 2):

Dividend paying companies maintain the same frequency of ex-dividend dates.  IOW, if they're quarterly, they remain quarterly.

I can't help you with API information but many web sites list historical dividends by date (for example, NASDAQ.com) and capturing 60+ days of them will provide all but the few who pay out on irregular schedules.